# Error al introducir las URL

Tags: laravel-5

Veran, en el código mi barra de usuario tengo añadido esto:

```
@if(auth()->user())
<img class="card-img-top" style="width: 50px; height: 50px;" src="{{auth()->user()->ruta()}}"/>
@endif
```

La función ruta se refiere a este código en User.php:

```
public function ruta(){
    return "storage/".$this->foto;
}
```

Gracias a esto, cuando un usuario se conecta, le aparece su foto.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Sin embargo, en ciertos enlaces la imagen falla.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Parece que al ser un url algo más complejo causa error. De hecho, puedo arreglarlo con este cambio en el metodo ruta:

```
public function ruta(){
    return "/bolsa/public/storage/".$this->foto;
}
```

Sin embargo es un buen tocho, por lo que me gustaria saber como poner la ruta de forma relativa.
Ademas, estando en esa ruta problematica me veo con otro apuro. Entre los iconos tengo otro llamado "cambiar imagen".
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero si lo hago desde la url compleja, me veo con esto.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Provisionalmente lo arreglo añadiendo en el href la función url:

```
<a class="nav-link" href="{{ url('/cambiar_foto') }}">Cambiar imagen</a>
```

Aunque tendra ahora su tela poner "url" a cada vista. ¿Hay un modo más sencillo?

Comment: se me ocurre esto `{{ asset(auth()->user()->ruta()) }}` partiendo de como tiene configurada en tu metodo `storage/ruta`

Comment: por lo que veo esta accediendo a laravel directo en al url que eso tambien puede ser un problema, lo mejor seria usar el comando `php artisan serve` o hacer una host virtual para poder trabajar bien con laravel

Comment: Yo uso el comando php artisan storage:link para enlacer las imagenes de storage en public. Aunque observo que si lo paso a otro PC se pierde la conexión.

Comment: @MiguelOsorio Agradeceria que explicases al detalle lo de PHP artisan serve, porque no tengo muy claro como es eso.

Comment: estas usando XAMPP o algo similar?

Comment: @MiguelOsorio Si, uso XAMPP.

Answer (score 2):

Bien una de las cosas que veo es que esta accediendo directamente a la ruta public para poder usar el proyecto de Laravel, y de ahi siempre tendrás algunos detalles de rutas por acceder de esa forma.
Te propongo lo siguiente para ver que tus datos se están mostrando de manera correcta.

Abre la consola de windos y ve hasta donde tienes la carpeta de tu proyecto por ejemplo `cd C:\Xammp\htdocs\miProyecto`.

Una vez dentro de tu proyecto corre el servicio que trae laravel por defecto para probar tu proyecto `php artisan serve` al hacer el comando te correra la aplicacion para acceder a ella en tu navegador ingresa con la siguiente ruta `http://127.0.0.1:8000` ya con eso podrás probar lo que tenia en un principio ya que al usar url te trae la ruta relativa del proyecto si mal no recuerdo entonces ya en tu blade podrás hacer lo siguiente

```
<img class="card-img-top" style="width: 50px; height: 50px;" src="{{ url('storage/'.auth()->user()->foto)}}"/>
```

ya con esto se debe mostrar bien las imágenes dependiendo como las estes guardando en storage.

Ahora bien si estas usando XAMPP
una forma fácil es crear hostVirtuales, para que puedas acceder a tu proyecto de una manera sencilla `mipaginaweb.com` por ejemplo.

**CONFIGURAR XAMPP**

**Configurar windows host**

1. Abre el bloc de notas como administrador
2. Abres el archivo ***hosts*** ubicado en ***C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc***
3. Te aparecera la resolucion de nombres de tu host agrega esta linea

`127.0.0.1  mipaginaweb.com`

o como quieras llamarle a tu dominio virtual

---

**Configurar httpd-vhosts de Xampp**

1. Desde el mismo bloc de notas abres el archivo **httpd-vhosts** ubicado en **C:\xampp\apache\conf\extra**
2. Agregas lo siguiente

   `<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/bolsa/public/"
    ServerName mipaginaweb.com
   </VirtualHost>`
3. Reinicia el servicio de xammp y podras acceder a la ruta `mipaginaweb.com` directamente

Comment: Así he hecho y ha salido bien. Como uso XAMPP, tendre que ver eso de las host virtuales...

Comment: ahorita te lo actualizo a host virtuales

Comment: @MiguelOsborio ¿Y...?

Comment: @MiguelAlparez checa la respuesta ya esta actualizada

Comment: Vale, he hecho lo que indicas y ahora puedo acceder a mi proyecto escribiendo http://bolsa.com

Comment: Eso si, ahora cuando tengo que escribir un correo electronico, se pone muy pesado con "conexión no segura". Aparte, veo que ahora las imagenes se pasan a almacenar en public/storage, aunque recibe las images almacenadas en storage/app/public.